# meteorjs - force iron-router to wait the render of all until waitOn finished

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am looking for a way to wait before rendering anything when a waitOn argument is given.

Currently it works perfectly with the recommended way:

1. use onBeforeAction ('loading')
2. use action : function (if (this.ready()) this.render())
3. waitOn : function () {return [Meteor.subscribe()...]}

   So when rendering the routing template the render process waits. But when I include a Template in the main-template the "sub"-Template will be rendered BEFORE the waitOn options ends.

So what is the recommended way to tell the iron-router to wait for the waitOn ready-state before render all included templates and also all yield-sub-templates ?

Comment: Can I ask where did you read it's the recommended way? I'm currently learning about Meteor and that would be really helpful.

Comment: It changed a lot how to do this. http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/  this is the latest guide. You can find examples for this problem in this guide. You have to use the this.ready() function to trigger reactive your this.render() functions.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works great:

```
this.route('note',{
    path: '/note/:_id', 
    waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('notes')},
    data: function() { 
        if( this.ready() ){ this.render();
            return Notes.findOne(this.params._id);
        }else{this.render('loading') }}
});
```

No content flashing or anything.

But also would like to know of how the guru's deal with it.

Comment: Hi yoK0 - I think you dont understood my question. What you did do the same as this what I did. My problem is not that the maintemplate (in your case 'node') snt waiting for the data - the problem is that the yield-templates (sub templates) are not waiting and also the templates which are rendered in the main template.

Comment: Hmm. This template goes into yield. Can you provide some code 'paste'.

Comment: I will upload tomorrow some code so you can see the problem.