# IronRouter: template is rendered before call in waitOn is finished

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I want to create charts based on data from my collection.
This data is called by an aggregate pull in my router-settings and set by Session.data in the template.rendered function.

The Meteor.call is placed in the waitOn-function. 
If the template is rendered, the data is not present.

I tried onBeforeAction, action, setTimeout... but i can't set the render-function to wait until the call-data is present.

I tried to set the calls in the onBeforeAction and onRun hooks, in the action, waitOn and data functions both on my RouteController and Router.route.

I wrapped my rendered-code with setTimeout, but it didn't work.

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'global',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
});
Router.onBeforeAction("loading");
```

is set in my global routing settings.

I've already tried following solutions:
[question 23575826](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575826/)
[question 26198531](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198531/)
https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/554#issuecomment-39002306
and more in the last days.

Is there any suggestion for my router settings or another way to solve this problem and get the data rendered in time? 
I consider to pick the npm-modules fiber/future, but i've no idea how to embed and use them.

My settings:
Meteor is v1.0.2.1

**router.js** with own controller

```
StatsController = RouteController.extend({
  template: 'statsShow',
  waitOn: function () {
    return [
      Meteor.call('saleGetDataPerYear', 'nYWpgxR3kEY8kwBkA', 'SellerOne', 2014, function(error, result){
        if(!error)
          Session.set('brockhausUnits', result['units']);
          Session.set('brockhausVolumes', result['volumes']); 
      }),
      Meteor.call('saleGetDataPerYear', 'nYWpgxR3kEY8kwBkA', 'SellerTwo', 2014, function(error, result){
        if(!error)
          Session.set('info3Units', result['units']);
          Session.set('info3Volumes', result['volumes']); 
      }),
      Meteor.call('saleGetDataPerYear', 'nYWpgxR3kEY8kwBkA', 'SellerThree', 2014, function(error, result){
        if(!error)
          Session.set('avaUnits', result['units']);
          Session.set('avaVolumes', result['volumes']);  
      })
    ];
  },
  data: function () {
    return Books.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
  },
  action: function () {
    if (!this.ready()) {
      this.render('Loading');
    } else {
      this.render(); 
    }
  }
});

Router.route('stats/show/', {
  name: 'stats.show',
  controller: 'TestController'
});
```

**methods.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
  saleGetDataPerYear: function(bookId, seller, year) {
    var sellerUnits = [];
    var sellerVolumes = [];
    var resultData = {};

    var pipeline = [
      {
        $match : { bookId: bookId, salesSeller: seller, salesYear: year }
      },
      {
        $group : {
          _id : {
            sale: { "salesMonth": "$salesMonth" }
          },
          units: { $sum: "$salesUnits" },
          volumes: { $sum: "$salesVolumes" },
          month: { $first: "$salesMonth" },
          year: { $first: "$salesYear" },
          seller: { $first: "$salesSeller" }   
        }
      },
      {
        $sort : {
          month: 1
        }
      }      
    ];    
    result = Sales.aggregate(pipeline);              

    if(result){
      sellerUnits.push(seller);
      sellerVolumes.push(seller);
      result.forEach(function(data){
        sellerUnits.push(data.units);
        sellerVolumes.push(data.volumes);
      });
      resultData['units'] = sellerUnits;
      resultData['volumes'] = sellerVolumes;
    }

    if(resultData){
      return resultData;     
    } else {
      throw new Meteor.Error("no-data", "No Data collected");
    }
  }
```

template

```
//-- template rendered functions
Template.statsShow.rendered = function(){ 
    var chartUnitsBrockhaus = Session.get('brockhausUnits');
    var chartUnitsInfo3 = Session.get('info3Units');
    var chartUnitsAva = Session.get('avaUnits');
    var chartUnitsSumme = Session.get('sumUnits');

    console.log(chartUnitsBrockhaus);

    var chartUnits = c3.generate({
      bindto: this.find('.chartUnits'),
      data: {
        columns: [
          chartUnitsBrockhaus,
          chartUnitsInfo3,
          chartUnitsAva,
          chartUnitsSumme   
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        types: {
          Summe: 'spline',
        },
      },
      axis: {
        x: {
          type: 'category',
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mär', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dez']
        }
      },
      bar: {
        width: {
          ratio: 0.5
        }
      }
    });       
};
```

packages

```
accounts-password             1.0.5
accounts-ui                   1.1.4 
alanning:roles                1.2.13
aldeed:autoform               4.2.2 
aldeed:autoform-select2       1.0.3
aldeed:collection2            2.3.1
aldeed:simple-schema          1.3.0 
anti:fake                     0.4.1
chrismbeckett:fontawesome4    4.2.2 
coffeescript                  1.0.5 
ctjp:meteor-bootstrap-switch  3.3.1_1 
dburles:collection-helpers    1.0.2 
francocatena:status           1.0.3  
iron:router                   1.0.7 
lepozepo:accounting           1.0.0 
less                          1.0.12  
matteodem:easy-search         1.4.6  
meteor-platform               1.2.1 
meteorhacks:aggregate         1.1.0   
mrt:jquery-csv                0.7.1  
natestrauser:select2          3.5.1  
nemo64:bootstrap              3.3.1_1 
ongoworks:security            1.0.1  
peerlibrary:xml2js            0.4.4_3 
peernohell:c3                 1.1.2 
sacha:spin                    2.0.4  
service-configuration         1.0.3  
underscore                    1.0.2 
zimme:select2-bootstrap3-css  1.4.1
```

**Edit**
as @DavidWeldon mentioned i changed my waitOn function to:

```
waitOn: function () {
  return [
    // first call
    Meteor.callWithReady('saleGetDataPerYear', 'nYWpgxR3kEY8kwBkA', 'Brockhaus', 2014, function(error, result){
      if(!error) {
        console.log(result); //debug
        Session.set('brockhausUnits', result['units']);
        Session.set('brockhausVolumes', result['volumes']);
      };          
    }),
    // second call
    Meteor.callWithReady('saleGetDataPerYear', 'nYWpgxR3kEY8kwBkA', 'Info3', 2014, function(error, result){
      if(!error) {
        console.log(result); //debug
        Session.set('brockhausUnits', result['units']);
        Session.set('brockhausVolumes', result['volumes']);
      };            
    }),
    // third call
    Meteor.callWithReady('saleGetDataPerYear', 'nYWpgxR3kEY8kwBkA', 'AVA', 2014, function(error, result){
      if(!error) {
        console.log(result); //debug
        Session.set('brockhausUnits', result['units']);
        Session.set('brockhausVolumes', result['volumes']);
      };            
    }),
    // fourth call
    Meteor.callWithReady('saleGetSumDataPerYear', 'nYWpgxR3kEY8kwBkA', 2014, function(error, result){
      if(!error) {
        console.log(result); //debug
        Session.set('sumUnits', result['units']);
        Session.set('sumVolumes', result['volumes']); 
      }           
    })   
  ];
},
```

and added *test.coffee* under /lib:

```
_.defaults Meteor,
  callWithReady: (method, options...) ->
    dep = new Deps.Dependency
    ready = false

    lastOption = _.last options
    if _.isFunction lastOption
      Meteor.apply method, _.initial(options), (err, result) ->
        lastOption err, result
        ready = true
        dep.changed()
    else
      Meteor.apply method, options, (err, result) ->
        ready = true
        dep.changed()

    ready: ->
      dep.depend()
      ready
```

result is: my calls loop.

I tested the answer from @apendua.

```
function waitUntilDone (action) {
  var isReady = new ReactiveVar(false);
  action(function () {
    isReady.set(true);
  });
  return {
    ready: function () {
      return isReady.get();
    }
  };
}

waitOn: function () {
  return [
    // first call
    waitUntilDone(function(done) {
      Meteor.callWithReady('saleGetDataPerYear', 'nYWpgxR3kEY8kwBkA', 'Brockhaus', 2014, function(error, result){
        if(!error) {
          console.log(result); //debug
          Session.set('brockhausUnits', result['units']);
          Session.set('brockhausVolumes', result['volumes']);
        };
        done();             
      })
    }),
    // second call
    waitUntilDone(function(done) {
      Meteor.call('saleGetDataPerYear', 'nYWpgxR3kEY8kwBkA', 'Info3', 2014, function(error, result){
        if(!error) {
          console.log(result); //debug
          Session.set('brockhausUnits', result['units']);
          Session.set('brockhausVolumes', result['volumes']);
          done();
        };            
      })
    }),
    // third call
    waitUntilDone(function(done) {
      Meteor.call('saleGetDataPerYear', 'nYWpgxR3kEY8kwBkA', 'AVA', 2014, function(error, result){
        if(!error) {
          console.log(result); //debug
          Session.set('brockhausUnits', result['units']);
          Session.set('brockhausVolumes', result['volumes']);
          done(); 
        };            
      })
    }),
    // fourth call
    waitUntilDone(function(done) {
      Meteor.call('saleGetSumDataPerYear', 'nYWpgxR3kEY8kwBkA', 2014, function(error, result){
        if(!error) {
          console.log(result);
          Session.set('sumUnits', result['units']);
          Session.set('sumVolumes', result['volumes']); 
          done(); 
        }           
      })
    })   
  ];
},
```

or

```
waitOn: function () {
  return [
    // first call
    waitUntilDone(function(done) {
      Meteor.callWithReady('saleGetDataPerYear', 'nYWpgxR3kEY8kwBkA', 'Brockhaus', 2014, function(error, result){
        if(!error) {
          console.log(result); //debug
          Session.set('brockhausUnits', result['units']);
          Session.set('brockhausVolumes', result['volumes']);
        };
        done();             
      }),
      Meteor.call('saleGetDataPerYear', 'nYWpgxR3kEY8kwBkA', 'Info3', 2014, function(error, result){
        if(!error) {
          console.log(result); //debug
          Session.set('brockhausUnits', result['units']);
          Session.set('brockhausVolumes', result['volumes']);
          done();
        };            
      })
      [...]
    })   
  ];
},
```

both results are: my calls loop.

Comment: `waitOn` is not going to work with `Meteor.call` right out of the box, you need some more elaborated code to make that working; where did you see this kind of example?

Comment: You can see my implementation of Meteor.callWithReady [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/294). It works for us in earlier versions of IR but I have not tested it with 1.x. You can try replacing your `Meteor.call` with `Meteor.callWithReady` and see if it works.

Comment: @apendua thats not from an example. i figured it out. I need the aggregate function to sum up some collection data and i dunno how this will work with subscriptions so i chose calls instead...

Comment: BTW, when after `if (!error)` you probably need to use braces to create a new block. Indentation does not create a new block like in `python`.

Comment: @David thanks, i will test your solution and report back

Comment: @DavidWeldon oh i must admit, i don't know where and how i shall write this code to extend or change meteor classes

Comment: Maybe just put it in a file under `/lib`.

Comment: yeah, i first copied it in a .js file, not coffee. it works now, but the calls are in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing here is that in your `waitOn` you need to return a list of objects, each of them having a `ready` method which acts as a reactive data source. Unfortunately, `Meteor.call` does not return this kind of object, but for example `Meteor.subscribe` does.

What you can do is to use the following wrapper but, make sure you have `reactive-var` package added to your project first.

```
function waitUntilDone (action) {
  var isReady = new ReactiveVar(false);
  action(function () {
    isReady.set(true);
  });
  return {
    ready: function () {
      return isReady.get();
    }
  };
}
```

Now, instead of returning a list of results of `Meteor.call` like this

```
waitOn: function () {
  return [
    Meteor.call(..., function () { ... }),
    Meteor.call(..., function () { ... }),
    // ...
  ]
}
```

use the above wrapper in the following way

```
waitOn: function () {
  return [
    waitUntilDone(function(done) {
      Meteor.call(..., function () {
        // ...
        done();
      }),
    }),
    // ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: I tested it out, but it's starting to loop my calls. Maybe it works with only one call per function?

Comment: Each single `Meteor.call` should be wrapped separately, if this is what you're asking. You need to show a bit more of your code if I am to give you more clues.

Comment: Thats what i've done. I also tried to put all in one 'waitUntilDone' function.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot insert the results of your aggregations into one or more collections server side and then publish them?  Then, building on the above comments, you just need to push your subscriptions to a waitlist array in your waitOn, and wait until they are all ready.

Answer (score 0):

Update: After some days of testing i changed the functions to `Meteor.publish` instead of `Meteor.method` so the `waitOn` function is now working.
i didn't realise that this also work with publish. The examples for aggregate db-calls are all with `Meteor.method`.

**publications.js**

```
Meteor.publish('saleGetAllDataPerYear', function(bookId, year) {
  self = this;

  var pipeBH = [];
  var resultBH = '';
  var unitsBH = [];
  var volumesBH = [];
  var monthBH = [];

  var pipeI3 = [];
  var resultI3 = '';
  var unitsI3 = [];
  var volumesI3 = [];
  var monthI3 = [];

  var pipeAVA = [];
  var resultAVA = '';
  var unitsAVA = [];
  var volumesAVA = [];
  var monthAVA = [];

  var pipeSum = [];
  var resultSum = '';
  var unitsSum = [];
  var volumesSum = [];
  var monthSum = [];

  // Set Brockhaus data  
  pipeBH = [
    { $match : { bookId: bookId, salesSeller: 'Brockhaus', salesYear: year } },
    { $group : { _id : { sale: { "salesMonth": "$salesMonth" } }, 
        units: { $sum: "$salesUnits" }, volumes: { $sum: "$salesVolumes" }, month: { $first: "$salesMonth" }, year: { $first: "$salesYear" }, seller: { $first: "$salesSeller" }   
      }
    },
    { $sort : { month: 1 } }
  ];
  resultBH = Sales.aggregate(pipeBH);

  if(resultBH != ''){
    unitsBH.push('Brockhaus');
    volumesBH.push('Brockhaus');
    resultBH.forEach(function(data){
      unitsBH.push(data.units);
      volumesBH.push(data.volumes);
      monthBH.push(data.month);
    });
    self.added('stats', Random.id(), {seller: 'Brockhaus', units: unitsBH, volumes: volumesBH, month: monthBH, year: year});
    self.ready();
  } else {
    self.ready();
  }

  // Set Info3 data
  pipeI3 = [
    { $match : { bookId: bookId, salesSeller: 'Info3', salesYear: year } },
    { $group : { _id : { sale: { "salesMonth": "$salesMonth" } }, 
        units: { $sum: "$salesUnits" }, volumes: { $sum: "$salesVolumes" }, month: { $first: "$salesMonth" }, year: { $first: "$salesYear" }, seller: { $first: "$salesSeller" }   
      }
    },
    { $sort : { month: 1 } }
  ];
  resultI3 = Sales.aggregate(pipeI3);

  if(resultI3 != ''){
    unitsI3.push('Info3');
    volumesI3.push('Info3');
    resultI3.forEach(function(data){
      unitsI3.push(data.units);
      volumesI3.push(data.volumes);
      monthI3.push(data.month);
    });
    self.added('stats', Random.id(), {seller: 'Info3', units: unitsI3, volumes: volumesI3, month: monthI3, year: year});
    self.ready();
  } else {
    self.ready();
  }

  // Set AVA data
  pipeAVA = [
    { $match : { bookId: bookId, salesSeller: 'AVA', salesYear: year } },
    { $group : { _id : { sale: { "salesMonth": "$salesMonth" } }, 
        units: { $sum: "$salesUnits" }, volumes: { $sum: "$salesVolumes" }, month: { $first: "$salesMonth" }, year: { $first: "$salesYear" }, seller: { $first: "$salesSeller" }   
      }
    },
    { $sort : { month: 1 } }
  ];
  resultAVA = Sales.aggregate(pipeAVA);

  if(resultAVA != ''){
    unitsAVA.push('AVA');
    volumesAVA.push('AVA');
    resultAVA.forEach(function(data){
      unitsAVA.push(data.units);
      volumesAVA.push(data.volumes);
      monthAVA.push(data.month);
    });
    self.added('stats', Random.id(), {seller: 'AVA', units: unitsAVA, volumes: volumesAVA, month: monthAVA, year: year});
    self.ready();
  } else {
    self.ready();
  }

  // Set Sum data
  pipeSum = [
    { $match : { bookId: bookId, salesYear: year } },
    { $group : { _id : { sale: { "salesMonth": "$salesMonth" } }, 
        units: { $sum: "$salesUnits" }, volumes: { $sum: "$salesVolumes" }, month: { $first: "$salesMonth" }, year: { $first: "$salesYear" }, seller: { $first: "$salesSeller" }   
      }
    },
    { $sort : { month: 1 } }
  ];
  resultSum = Sales.aggregate(pipeSum);

  if(resultSum != ''){
    unitsSum.push('Summe');
    volumesSum.push('Summe');
    resultSum.forEach(function(data){
      unitsSum.push(data.units);
      volumesSum.push(data.volumes);
      monthSum.push(data.month);
    });
    self.added('stats', Random.id(), {seller: 'Summe', units: unitsSum, volumes: volumesSum, month: monthSum, year: year});
    self.ready();
  } else {
    self.ready();
  }
});
```

**router.js**

```
waitOn: function () {
  year = Number(Session.get('year'));
  return [
    Meteor.subscribe('saleGetAllDataPerYear', this.params._id, year),
    Meteor.subscribe('getStats')
  ];
},
```

Thanks to @JeremyS for the inspiration on another way. That sounds like the better solution because now the `waitOn` function works but the data is not rendered in my chart without manual refresh of my template.